# How to count the first 30 letters in a string ignoring spaces

Tags: php

I want to take a post description but only display the first, for example, 30 letters but ignore any tabs and spaces.

```
$msg = 'I only need the first, let us just say, 30 characters; for the time being.';
$msg .= ' Now I need to remove the spaces out of the checking.';

$amount = 30;

// if tabs or spaces exist, alter the amount
if(preg_match("/\s/", $msg)) {
    $stripped_amount = strlen(str_replace(' ', '', $msg));
    $amount = $amount + (strlen($msg) - $stripped_amount);
}

echo substr($msg, 0, $amount);
echo '<br /> <br />';
echo substr(str_replace(' ', '', $msg), 0, 30);
```

The first output gives me **'I only need the first, let us just say, 30 characters;'** and the second output gives me: **Ionlyneedthefirst,letusjustsay** so I know this isn't working as expected.

My desired output in this case would be:

```
I only need the first, let us just say
```

Thanks in advance, my maths sucks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get the part with the first 30 characters with a regular expression:

```
$msg_short = preg_replace('/^((\s*\S\s*){0,30}).*/s', '$1', $msg);
```

With the given `$msg` value, you will get in `$msg_short`:

> I only need the first, let us just say

#### Explanation of the regular expression

- `^`: match must start at the beginning of the string
- `\s*\S\s*` a non-white-space (`\S`) surrounded by zero or more white-space characters (`\s*`)
- `(\s*\S\s*){0,30}` repeat finding this sequence up to 30 times (greedy; get as many as possible within that limit)
- `((\s*\S\s*){0,30})` the parentheses make this series of characters group number 1, which can be referenced as `$1`
- `.*` any other characters. This will match all remaining characters, because of the `s` modifier at the end:
- `s`: makes the dot match new line characters as well

In the replacement only the characters are maintained that belong to group one (`$1`). All the rest is ignored and not included in the returned string.

Comment: preg replace is so powerful, could you send me some documentation on this? I am so confused to how that works... +1

Comment: You can play with this on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xzwNFi/1). See also [some tutorials on regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: marked as answer so visitors can see most elegant + explanation. Thank's again!

Comment: I've tested both trincot's and my answer in terms of performance and while my solution is 2 milliseconds faster in PHP 7.1 (system time), trincot's solution wins the race for the user time by 6 milliseconds. So, you are right to mark his answer as the best one. +1

Comment: Yeah, I also ran tests in [3v4l](http://3v4l.org). Although your answer was first and still answers my question, I just thought for other SO users, this answer is most elegant. Still +1 on your answer and I appreciate your time! @Paul

Answer (score 3):

Spontaneously, there are two ways to achieve that I can think of.

The first one is close to what you did already. Take the first 30 characters, count the spaces and take as many next characters as you found spaces until the new set of letters has no spaces in it anymore.

```
$msg = 'I only need the first, let us just say, 30 characters; for the time being.';
$msg .= ' Now I need to remove the spaces out of the checking.';
$amount = 30;
$offset = 0;
$final_string = '';
while ($amount > 0) {
  $tmp_string = substr($msg, $offset, $amount);
  $amount -= strlen(str_replace(' ', '', $tmp_string));
  $offset += strlen($tmp_string);
  $final_string .= $tmp_string;
}
print $final_string;
```

The second technique would be to explode your string at spaces and put them back together one by one until you hit your threshold (where you would eventually need to break down a single word into characters).

Comment: 'count the spaces' - I like that, how did I not think of that. +1

Comment: I updated the question using the idea, could you review it? It's still not giving me the result.

Comment: I added an example out of my head for the first way. Tested it online (http://phptester.net/), seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out if it works:

```
<?php
$string= 'I only need the first, let us just say, 30 characters; for the time being.';

echo "Everything: ".strlen($string);
echo '<br />';
echo "Only alphabetical: ".strlen(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $string));
?>
```

Comment: On the right track, but please be aware, that `[^a-zA-Z]` will remove all digits and punctuation as well.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done this way.

```
$tmp=str_split($string);//split the string
$result="";
$i=0;$j=0;
while(isset($tmp[$i]) && $j<30){
  if(trim($tmp[$i])){//test for non space and count
   $j++;
  }
 $result .= $tmp[$i++];
}
print $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know regex too well so...

```
<?php
$msg = 'I only need the first, let us just say, 30 characters; for the time being. Now I need to remove the spaces out of the checking.';

$non_space_hit = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($msg); ++$i)
{
    echo $msg[$i];

    $non_space_hit+= (int)($msg[$i] !== ' ' && $msg[$i] !== "\t");

    if($non_space_hit === 30)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

You end up with:

> I only need the first, let us just say